# Android: Playing video issue

Tags: android

Out there, there are a lot of examples about how to play video on Android (API level 16).
But I can't understand why they don't work for me.

This is a simple example:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="my.owm.package" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ContentActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_content" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_content.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="my.owm.package.ContentActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

contentActivity.java

```
public class ContentActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = ContentActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);

        VideoView videoView =(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/Movies/test.mp4");
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();

    }
}
```

The test.mp4 files is actually there and runs fine with any player (btw it's a H264 w/ Baseline Profile). Anyway i tried several other videos, most of them used by the authors of the tutorial on this topic.

I get no errors but no video and no audio.
I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious because I found this code in a lot of Android tutorials!

Any idea?
Thanks!

EDIT:

I run the code on a physical device.
However I discovered the code is actually working until I add the following item in the layout xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp" />
```

Comment: Are you testing on an emulator or a device? Sometimes there are issues with video on the emulator.

Comment: Honestly I messed up something during trials. So I copied the code from the wrong activity. I'm editing the original question right now, but I don't know if I should open a different question.

Comment: Mark i have added running code are here working

Answer (score 1):

I worked on this way :

```
public class AnVideoView extends Activity {


 String SrcPath = "/sdcard/Video/Android in Spaaaaaace!_low.mp4";




/** Called when the activity is first created. */



 @Override



 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



 setContentView(R.layout.main);

       VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
       myVideoView.setVideoPath(SrcPath);
       myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
       myVideoView.requestFocus();
       myVideoView.start();

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have come across issues with `VideoView` like this across multiple devices before.

Firstly I would consider re-encoding your videos using a tool such as `ffmpeg` that can be downloaded [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).

The following encoding has always worked for me:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -c:a libfaac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 128k -movflags faststart output.mp4
```

Alternatively, some devices cannot handle videos with 'large' dimensions. Try resizing your videos to a smaller size and seeing if that helps also.

Comment: As I said the video runs fine with a lot of Android players. So it MUST run with mine too :-) Anyway, I've updated the question because I found the DrawerLayout prevents the video from playing.

Comment: In previous cases the videos I have used have also worked on other players, but not on the default `VideoView` such as you described. Glad to see you resolved your issue

Comment: Thus should be useful to know which alternative to VideoView is recommended to play those videos! Furthermore, i didn't solve the issue because I need the DrawerLayout, but when I add it to the layout the video doesn't run anymore.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: the DrawerLayout should be added at the END of the layout... it seems the order is important!